# What is the best way to prevent highlighting of text when clicking on its containing div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a menu in HTML/CSS/JS and I need a way to prevent the text in the menu from being highlighted when double-clicked on. I need a way to pass the id's of several divs into a function and have highlighting turned off within them.

So when the user accidentally (or on purpose) double clicks on the menu, the menu shows its sub-elements but its text does not highlight.

There are a number of scripts out there floating around on the web, but many seem outdated. What's the best way?

Comment: Why do you feel a need to prevent a user's text-selection?

Comment: I had a similar question and found this useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In (Mozilla, Firefox, Camino, Safari, Google Chrome) you can use this:

```
div.noSelect {
  -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
  -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit browsers */
}
```

For IE there is no CSS option, but you can capture the ondragstart event, and return false;

**Update**

Browser support for this property has expanded since 2008.

```
div.noSelect {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10 and IE 11 */
  user-select: none; /* Standard syntax */
}
```

[https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_user-select.php](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/)

Comment: Is mozilla its own browser? :)

Comment: Mozilla is the internal name for the rendering engine inside "Mozilla Firefox" as well as Camino, and the base Mozilla browser... and well Netscape before that.  So yes Mozilla is its own browser but it really is best known as the rendering engine used in Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this CSS to simply hide the selection color (not supported by IE):

```css
#id::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}

#id::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Give it ("it" being your text) a onclick event
- First click sets a variable to the current time
- Second click checks to see if that variable is x time from the current, current time (so a double click over, for example, 500ms, doesn't register as a double click)
- If it *is* a double click, do something to the page like adding hidden HTML, doing document.focus(). You'll have to experiment with these as some might cause unwanted scrolling.

Comment: If you're trying to do this as a soft-DRM, please drop the idea! People could do control+a or just read the source.

Comment: Thanks, but I know there must be a more elegant solution. The scripts out there now that work do not use timers.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function clearSelection() {
    var sel;
    if (document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
      document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel && sel.removeAllRanges)
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    }
  } 
</script>

<div ondblclick="clearSelection()">Some text goes here.</div>
```