# Select nothing on the page with JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, highlight

I have a jQuery slider that requires being slid, but if the user drags there mouse past the sliders end, it highlights some of the things on the rest of the page. Now if the user goes to move the slider again, it does this weird thing where it tries to drag the highlighted elements instead of the slider. What I'm looking for is a jQuery or JavaScript blurb that sets nothing to be highlighted. I tried `$('body').blur();` but with no avail.

Comment: We need at least some code to try to figure out what is the problem..

Comment: I already knew what the problem was, it was highlighting things and I needed to un-highlight them. Someone posted the answer already anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This posting has information on how to clear the text selection with JavaScript: [Clear Text Selection with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks! I searched forever for this but could not find the answer