# How to deselect selected HTML in a grid using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, events

I have a **JQuery-based** *single-page web application* with a rich Knockout-based grid.

When I double-click on a row in the Knockout grid, I load a virtual page of data with the details for the selected item, and when I'm done editing it (or if I cancel), I'm returned to the grid.  All of this happens on a single page.

If I double-click on a non-text area in the grid or if I set focus to an input field in the form, everything works great when the grid is redisplayed. But if I double-click on some text in a row (like the row item's "Name") and then immediately click "Cancel" to return to the grid, then all of grid's HTML is selected when I redisplay it. It's as if I had clicked and dragged through the grid to select a giant region of text.

I've been trying to **programmatically deselect this selected text** but to no avail. I've tried various combinations of:

```
$(document).focus();
$("#idBody").focus();
$("#idBody").trigger("click");
```

If I click on a region outside the grid, I get the behavior I want. What are my options?

Comment: If I explicitly set focus to an input field in the edit form, then I get the behavior I want. So, this is only a problem if the user double-clicks to edit details and then immediately clicks "Cancel". For now, I'm going to set focus to the first input field in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem when double clicking is that by performing that action browsers by default select the text under the cursor, creating a range of selected text.

Working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/rq5Wq/)!

**This solved me the same problem in the past by removing that range of selected text:**

```
if (window.getSelection) {
  if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
    window.getSelection().empty();
  } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
} else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
  document.selection.empty();
}
```

**You can read about it:**

[window.getSelection at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) and [DOM Selection at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection#Methods)

[removeAllRanges method at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [HTMLSelection object at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

Credit for this solution goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169849/352449) and [Mr. Y.](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-layout/browse_thread/thread/875b5f2ae68821b6).

---

## TESTED ON

**Windows XP Profissional versão 2002 Service Pack 3**

- Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 3.6.16
- Safari 5.1.2
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m
- K-Meleon 1.5.4

**Windows 7 Home Edition Service Pack 1**

- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.164211C
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 12.0
- Safari 5.1.4
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m

**Linux Ubuntu 12.04**

- Firefox 12.0
- Chromium 18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux)

Comment: Excellent answer. What an elegant solution. I've now added this to my utilities namespace as ns.utils.clearSelectedText(). I verified the fix with IE8, Firefox (12), Chrome (19) and Opera (11.6). I'll check with IE9 later and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: I just verified with IE9 as well. Works great.

Comment: I'll add the "test case" to the answer soon enough, just finishing up the tests :) Tks!

Comment: @Armchair Bronco, added the test case suite :)