# After clicking on selected text, window selection is not giving updated range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After double click, selection range can be obtained correctly on onclick event but when I again click on the selected text then updated selection range should be returned by window selection but this is not happening. Can anybody tell me if this is a bug in javascript selection or they have made it this way. And what could be the solution to get the updated range apart from timer.

```
<div id="xyz" contenteditable="true">Hello world</div>
<span class="status">Selected text : </span>
```

javascript code :

```
function yourFunction() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
         var selectionRange = window.getSelection();
         $('.status').text(selectionRange.toString());
    }
}

$('#xyz').click(function () {
    $('.status').text('Mouse click');
    yourFunction();
})
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zRr4s/20/)

Comment: Example can be found on this link : jsfiddle.net/zRr4s/20

Comment: your fiddle is working perfectly fine

Comment: after selecting some text you can get selection range. but again click on the selected text and observe. it will give you the old selection range.

Comment: Just stepped on it. It works as expected in Edge, but NOT in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fiddle is working just fine. But, yes sometimes when you do selections in quick succession, then it fails to register the click.

The problem really lies in the way you have implemented it on `click` on the text `input` itself. A *click* event is generated when a *mouseup* follows a *mousedown*. A selection happens when you *mousedown* then *drag* and then *mouseup*.

If you separate out the selection retrieval then this problem won't occur.

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRr4s/21/

Here, the selection retrieval is donw on a button click, instead of the input itself.

i.e., instead of:

```
$('#xyz').click(function (e) { ...
```

using this:

```
$('#btn').click(function () { ...
```

where, btn is:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="get selection" />
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**:

If you insist on handling event only on the input, then listening *mouseup* would be better option:

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRr4s/22/

```
$('#xyz').on("mouseup", function (e) { ...
```

**Update 2**:

To handle your requirement of in-context click, you will have to first clear the selection. For this to happen you will have to handle *mousedown*. So, that will defeat your purpose of having only one handler. Anyway,

You updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/zRr4s/29/**

And, this is how you do it:

```
$('#xyz').on("mousedown", function () {
    clearTheSelection();
});
```

Where `clearTheSelection` is another function:

```
function clearTheSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
      if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
        window.getSelection().empty();
      } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      }
    } else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
      document.selection.empty();
    }
}
```

The complete code for the above function taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169849/1355315

Hope that completes all your problems.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intent. Actually I want to have one listener which can immediately give me the range as soon as click 
completed. window selection refreshes its selection range when you click on the button not just after you finishes your clicking. (in case of clicking on a selected text)

Comment: @mukeshKumar: there you go. updated the answer. handle *mouseup* instead of *click*.

Comment: updated fiedel is still giving the wrong result. 
step to reproduce: 
1. select some text
2. click on selected text

Comment: when you select some text say "Hello" then you can see this word in status div. Again when you click between 'H' and 'ello' you can see that same word "Hello" is getting displayed while nothing should get displayed as nothing has been selected.

Comment: @mukeshKumar: that is not a problem. that is how it works. unless the context is lost, the selection will remain. you are not moving from the current selection and hence context is still active. if you just click outside the context then it will be lost.

Comment: According to my application this is a problem. So can you suggest any solution for this ???

Comment: @mukeshKumar: well, that's the way it works. you can't change that.

Comment: I understand dude but there must be some alternative solution to achieve that.

Comment: @mukeshKumar: there you go. updated the answer. hope that helps.

Comment: I really appreciates your effort but I just want to tell you that I have also tried the same thing and it was working fine on chrome and mozila but it created side effect on IE. On IE you can not select whole line/paragraph by double/tripple click.

Comment: @mukeshKumar: of course i can select entire line/para by triple-click on ie.

Comment: If you are trying http://jsfiddle.net/zRr4s/29/ then it is not abe to fire even mousedown event. Can you share the fiedel where you tried plz ??

Comment: @mukeshKumar: Ok got it now. IE is actually behaving strangely. Sorry, mate I won't be able to help you further on this.

Comment: Clearing the selection - you are a true gentleman and a scholar. Thank you!

Comment: There are two problems with this solution. 1) It takes a risky path of changing built-in browser text selection logic within mouse event handlers; 2) It still fails if your text selection was changed not by clicking (example: select some text, then type anything).

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle provided in the question works fine in Edge and IE11 but doesn't work in Chrome. I found a trick to make it work everywhere. Add the following event handler **in addition to** the `click` handler you already have:

```
$(document).on("selectionchange", function () {
    yourFunction();
});
```

Some notes:

1. `selectionchange` is a document level event, you cannot bind it to specific element (but you can find out whether you need to handle it within the event handler)
2. Handling `selectionchange` without also handling `click` doesn't work well in Edge and IE11

According to MDN, browser support is good enough: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event