# Get selection range values inside another selection in contentEditable

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I have a contentditable element.
When user selects some text, I know about it using a keyup event. I'm interested in knowing when and if the selection has changed from last selection.

The problem is (see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r80dfr72/1/)):

html:

```
<div id="div1" contenteditable="true">This is a sample text</div>
```

js:

```
 $(function(){
  var selectedRange, selectedNode;
  $("#div1").on("keyup mouseup", function(e) {
    selectedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    selectedNode = selectedRange.commonAncestorContainer;
    console.log("selected node: ", selectedNode);
    console.log("selected node value: ", selectedNode.nodeValue);
    console.log("selection chars range: START POS: ", selectedRange.startOffset);
    console.log("selection chars range: END POS: ", selectedRange.endOffset);
  });
});
```

When a user selects some text, and then **selects another text within the first selection's range** (or just puts the caret inside the selected range) - the range object returns the wrong value, claiming that the selection hasn't been changed.

Only after second selection/ mouse click will the range object return the correct value.

It is very important for me to know the selection has changed on the first mouse click.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442158/selection-change-event-in-contenteditable) answer, 3 years ago, hoping things have changed by now.

Please note I'm supporting all major browsers (ie >=10) (e.g. no "selectstart" event in firefox).

Here's how to reproduce this issue:

1. Go to the fiddle attached, run the code and open web console.
2. In the output window, select the word "sample" using the mouse, starting from letter "s" , releasing the mouse after letter "e".
3. Notice the console saying the start offset ("POS") is 10 & end offset is 16.
4. click with the mouse inside the word "sample", between letters "m" to letter "p" (selecting nothing).
5. Notice the web console, the range start position & end position are told to stay the same.
6. Repeat step 4.
7. Notice correct values return by Range API now - position is 13.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a step-by-step on how to reproduce the "error"? (i.e. paste this, copy that, notice this, error only visible if using keyboard etc.)

Comment: @Mackan I've added reproducing steps.

Answer (score 3):

One way to make sure that the selection is reset, is to actually reset it on a click. You could use `mousedown` for example:

```
$("#div1").on("keyup mouseup mousedown", function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
      clearTheSelection();
  } else {
      selectedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      selectedNode = selectedRange.commonAncestorContainer;
      console.log("selection chars range: START POS: ", selectedRange.startOffset);
      console.log("selection chars range: END POS: ", selectedRange.endOffset);
  }
});

function clearTheSelection() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
      if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
         window.getSelection().empty();
      } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
         window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      }
  } else if (document.selection) {  // IE
      document.selection.empty();
  }
}
```

I have [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r80dfr72/2/) with an example

Also, the *clearTheSelection()* I got from another SO answer: [After clicking on selected text, window selection is not giving updated range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775824/after-clicking-on-selected-text-window-selection-is-not-giving-updated-range)

Edit:

Actually, it seems Chrome and FF can use the same method for clearing selection. That leaves us with:

```
function clearTheSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        document.selection.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also managed to solve this issue by putting the logic within a timer with time of 0, meaning it will be fired immediately after last browser operation in the browser operation stack order, thus returning the correct values.

I've updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r80dfr72/3/).

```
$(function(){
  var selectedRange, selectedNode, timer;
  $("#div1").on("keyup mouseup", function(e) {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      selectedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      selectedNode = selectedRange.commonAncestorContainer;
      console.log("selected node: ", selectedNode);
      console.log("selected node value: ", selectedNode.nodeValue);
      console.log("selection chars range: START POS: ", selectedRange.startOffset);
      console.log("selection chars range: END POS: ", selectedRange.endOffset);
      clearTimeout(timer);
    },0);
  });
});
```