# How to clear text selection in Mobile Safari with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, selection

Is there a way to programmatically clear a selection box in Mobile Safari?  I tried `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()` as suggested by the answers to another Stack Overflow question, [Clear Text Selection with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3169786/196844), and while the Selection object is reset to no selection (type is "None", isCollapsed is `true`, rangeCount is 0, and the `anchorNode`/`focusNode`/`baseNode`/`extentNode` are `null`), the selection box remains on screen:

[image: Screenshot of the 'Clear Text Selection with JavaScript' question on Stack Overflow, showing the selection box still on screen]

I also tried `window.getSelection().collapse()`, but that did not work.

I am testing iOS 7.1 Simulator as well as Mobile Safari on an iPad running iOS 7.1.1.

Comment: did u get work around for dis. I need it badly . plz help to remove selection highlight in ipad using javascript/jquery

Comment: @Khaleel: No, sorry.  Though I did find out that this problem has been reported to Apple at least twice.  See: http://www.openradar.me/8707236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a known bug in Mobile Safari since 2010!    http://www.openradar.me/8707236

The year is now 2018 and this is still a bug. (iOS 10.2.2)

In areas where it was not needed, removing `event.preventDefault()` helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and in my case what made a difference was removing

```
event.preventDefault();
```

from the handler of the "deselection" tap event.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to quickly add and remove the `user-select` CSS class of the parent element, to disable and enable the user selection.

For example,

```
parent = getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode
parent.style.userSelect = "none"
setTimeout(()=>parent.style.userSelect = <default>, 100)
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I just tried it in iOS 11.1 Simulator and it didn't clear the selection either visually or via window.getSelection(). Also, user-select appears to need the `-webkit` prefix in Mobile Safari.

Comment: It doesn't work the first select + deselect, but it works every time after that. Bizarre behavior, but I don't expect much from Apple.