# Deselect contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove selection inside a contenteditable field. The code I have is this:

```
<h1 contenteditable>Text</h1>
<input type="text" value="Text" /><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="" value='Deselect input'>
<input type="button" onclick="$('h1').blur()" value='Deselect h1'>
```

And I'm auto-selecting the `h1`'s text via `document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);`

Removing the selection for the input works, but it does not work for the `h1`. How can I achieve this?

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8r9L4a3/3/)

---

this photo shows how it behaves for me:

[image]

As you can see I just clicked `deselect h1` and the text is still selected. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: For me it works fine. Which browser do you use?

Comment: The H1 text doesn't get auto-selected in your fiddle, but de-selection works fine for me too.

Comment: @Yuri yes, the auto selection was something I while editing, and forgot to update. Should auto-select the h1 now.

Comment: Make that <h1> an <input> with equivalent font-size, because auto-select is exclusive for form fields I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer here solved my problem, but it got deleted for some reason. It was this:

Replacing `$('h1').blur()` with `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();"` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript) on SO, and should be what you are looking for:

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
        window.getSelection().empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
} else if (document.selection) {  // IE?
    document.selection.empty();
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8r9L4a3/5/)

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').focus();
  document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
})

$("#deselect").click(function(){
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v73e3xdf/2/