# The opposite to window.getSelection()

Tags: javascript

I am selecting a text to copy it by using **window.getSelection().addRange(range)**:

```
  var targetelement = document.getElementById("someid"), 
  range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(targetelement);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy')
```

It works, but the browser(firefox) selects the text inside the tag after the completion of the code. How can I diselect it? Is there some kind of opposite to **window.getSelection** function or method?

Comment: Can you just select "" to 'diselect it'? Also can you show what Firefox is doing versus what you want to happen?

Comment: Most likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear Text Selection with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="someid">
This is a test man
</div>

<div id="empty">
</div>


<script>
    var targetelement = document.getElementById("someid");
    var  range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(targetelement);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy');  

   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s1teLukn/5/

Comment: Menelaos Bakopoulos, what do I have to add in this case? Explain me please.  window.getSelection().empty; ?

Comment: window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

Answer (score 1):

After copy trigger a [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) or [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur) to this input field to diselect the text.

Answer (score 1):

This old code works in all browsers:

```
var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection;

if (sel) {
    if (sel.removeAllRanges) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
    } else if (sel.empty) {
        sel.empty();
   }
}
```