# how to fix copy to clipboard bug in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Using the following code I have a function that copies a specified elements text range, however if I have multiple on the same page and try to use both buttons to copy different elements it always only pastes the first one you clicked.

Not sure if I explained that well so here's an example:

```
A = abc

B = xyz

Button1 = CopyToClipboard('A')

Button2 = CopyToClipboard('B')

//If I clicked button1 then button2 I would get the contents of button1 (abc).
```

Both buttons work but after you click one you can't copy another.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a id="A">abc</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="CopyToClipboard('A')">COPY</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a id="B">xyz</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="CopyToClipboard('B')">COPY</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
  if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
}
```

Edit:
Link to code snippet: https://plnkr.co/edit/z5bCymHPgEdTQhYShlMR?p=preview

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right but I think your code works just fine for me when I run it. Are you sure you don't have another typo maybe?

Comment: Yeah, here's the website I'm developing https://www.maxmears.com/io/ if you scroll down to the 'OUR SERVERS' part and try to copy the server IP's you'll see what I mean. FWI: I haven't done any max css for resolutions less than 1440p so it will look broken if your screen resolution is less than 1440p

Comment: As I see in your example when I click in one button and after that in the other one, it copies both values. Would you please look at this plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/cSLAb6qRMIfqzF6yV0dE?p=preview, and tell me if it works fine or not.

Comment: I can't click the buttons on that, I forgot to add that the A tags have a href set so they're clickable: https://plnkr.co/edit/z5bCymHPgEdTQhYShlMR?p=preview

Comment: Actually they are clickable and also they do their job, it just do not show the hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as you add `href` to your `<a>` the `window` does not clear all selected strings, and so it copies both values. I'm not sure how to fix this but here is a hack to it (**add this code in the top of your `CopyToClipboard(containerid)` function**):

```js
if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
  window.getSelection().empty();
} else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}
```

which as you know clear all text selections base on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should use clipboard.js plugin.
[Here Is The Link](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I find the anyone's answer here

```
<script>

window.onload = function () {

    var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.js-textareacopybtn');

    copyTextareaBtn.forEach(function(btn){
        btn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var copyTextarea = document.getElementById(this.dataset.txtid);
        copyTextarea.select();

        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
                alert('Copying text command was ' + msg);
            } catch (err) {
                alert('Whoops, unable to copy');
            }
        })

    });
}

</script>

<p>Test #1 </p>

<div>
<textarea id="txta1" class="js-copytextarea" readonly="readonly" style="width:20%;" 
rows="5">Hello. This is textarea test bed #1</textarea>
<button data-txtid="txta1" class="js-textareacopybtn">Copy Text (works)</button>

<p>Test #2:</p>

<textarea id="txta2" class="js-copytextarea" readonly="readonly" style="width:20%;" 
rows="5">Hi! Welcome to textarea test bed #2 </textarea>
<button data-txtid="txta2" class="js-textareacopybtn">Copy Text</button>

</div>
```