# stopping firefox from selecting content on webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to prevent highlighting of text when clicking on its containing div in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139157/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-highlighting-of-text-when-clicking-on-its-contain)

When a user clicks and drags how do you stop firefox from highlighting your content?

Comment: As @TheifMaster has said, we know how much you accept answers, and the more you do, the more likely it is that the *smart guys* will give you an answer. (`smart != nice`) You can do this by clicking on the **check mark** below the *down vote* button.

Comment: Please note: Anybody determined enough will find a way to copy stuff off of your page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been answered here:
[What is the best way to prevent highlighting of text when clicking on its containing div in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139157/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-highlighting-of-text-when-clicking-on-its-contain)

Basically, for firefox, you should be able to do this in CSS:

```
div.noSelect {
  -moz-user-select: none;//mozilla browsers
  -khtml-user-select: none;//webkit browsers
}
```

For IE you can apparently "add a handler to the ondragstart event, and return false;"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery UI on your page, you can simply use `$('body').disableSelection();`

If not, try this (this is what `disableSelection()` does):

```
var elem = document.body;
elem.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
elem.MozUserSelect = 'none';
elem.unselectable = 'on';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `unselectable` expando property in IE and CSS in other browsers. See this answer for more details: [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4358620#4358620)