# How to click a div that has text in it without highlighting/selecting the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the best way to prevent highlighting of text when clicking on its containing div in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139157/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-highlighting-of-text-when-clicking-on-its-contai)

I'm building my own simple counter with `+` and `-` text buttons (divs). I have it where it does a .focus() on another div, the `.countDisplay` which should take the focus *off of* the count buttons.  Best by example: http://jsbin.com/uxewej/2/edit If you click the `+` button a few times consecutively, it sometimes looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the text from being selected/highlighted like that if the user clicks either of the buttons in succession?  Thanks!

Comment: There are threads on this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting.

Comment: Would it be possible to just make them images and text-align the real + and - off to the side?

Comment: @afEkenholm sorry you was 100% right, `disableSelection` is jquery UI.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery

Comment: I've tried all of these suggestions (including using buttons), to no avail on an android phone using Chrome browser :(

Answer (score 2):

You can do the trick using CSS : http://jsbin.com/uxewej/8/

```
html{
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -khtml-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  user-select:none;
}
```

Do not use `html` CSS selector if you need to let the user select something.

**Update**

Tested with FF, Chrome and IE9

Generic solution in complement of CSS declarations

```
function toggleEnableSelectStart(enable) {
    document.onmousedown = function (e) { return enable; };
    document.onselectstart = function (e) { return enable; };
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //Disable default text selection behavior
    toggleEnableSelectStart(false);

    //Let inputs text selection possible
    jQuery("input[type=text]").focusin(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(true); });
    jQuery("input[type=text]").mouseover(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(true); });
    jQuery("input[type=text]").focusout(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(false); });
    jQuery("input[type=text]").mouseout(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(false); });
});
```

Sorry about the author, I don't remember where I found that one day, but it is clever!

**Update 2**

To avoid the clicking selection behavior only on your button, remove the CSS tricks and use

http://jsbin.com/uxewej/11/edit

```
function toggleEnableSelectStart(enable) {
    document.onmousedown = function (e) { return enable; };
    document.onselectstart = function (e) { return enable; };
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//Disable default text selection behavior
toggleEnableSelectStart(false);

//Let inputs text selection possible
jQuery(".countButton").focusin(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(false); });
jQuery(".countButton").mouseover(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(false); });
jQuery(".countButton").focusout(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(true); });
jQuery(".countButton").mouseout(function () { toggleEnableSelectStart(true); });
});
```

**Update 3**

If you want to disable selection on selected element follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700000/how-to-disable-text-selection-using-jquery)

```
(function($){
    $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
        return this
                 .attr('unselectable', 'on')
                 .css('user-select', 'none')
                 .on('selectstart', false);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: If i click anywhere, everything is selected :) FF 18.0.1

Comment: I have updated my answer with a cross-browser solution

Comment: Nice, but he want to make it only on buttons :))

Comment: So, just rewrite a part of my solution. Check my update

Comment: I don't understand why you would go this far, when changing the tag to the semantically more correct button tag solves this problem anyway. Your solution works, of course, I just don't get it.

Comment: @pentzzsolt there is a question, so there is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use button tags instead of span, it makes more sense semantically and just works better for this scenario as well. And of course solves your problem.

Comment: I was pretty excited about this idea, but, it still selects the button on an android phone using Chrome :/

Comment: Oh boy, can't keep up with all these devices. :(

Answer (score 1):

You just have to disable text selection. jQuery can do this, and it should be cross-browser:

```
$(".countButton").attr("unselectable", "on")
.on("selectstart", false)
.css("user-select", "none");
```