# Prevent text highlight when click

Tags: javascript

I have a input field with plus minus sign to raise/lower the number in it. Looks like this:

```
<a onclick="less()">-</a>
<input type="text" text-input">
<a onclick="more()">+</a>
```

How can I disable/prevent the select/highlight of the +/- text when I click to raise the numbers?

I'm looking for a solution that works cross browser. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to prevent highlighting of text when clicking on its containing div in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139157/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-highlighting-of-text-when-clicking-on-its-contai)

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid. An anchor *must* have either a `name` or `href` attribute. You might want to use a simple `span` element.

Comment: Make them buttons instead of text links.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, I'm aware, just wanted to simplify. I have more properties in the inputs also.

Comment: If CSS3 is an option, you can use the ::selection selector to set the background color of selected text so that it's the same as the background color of the input

Comment: @DevlshOne, buttons seems better markup, you are right. Will do your suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending of what versions of browsers you have to support, you can try using css property `user-select` to `none`. Here you have an example of such implementation http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Comment: that did it. Didn't know there were a CSS for that. Thanks.

Comment: @Rikard Glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 4):

you can use css `::selection`

```
::selection {
  background: none;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: none;
}
::-webkit-selection {
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is to have `<button>` doing that.
Then both your highlight problem is solved and you write code in a better way.

(you can also change buttons with CSS so they look like you want)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
      .linklike { color: blue; text-decoration:underline  }        
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="less()">-</button>
    <input type="text">
    <button onclick="more()">+</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    OR<br
    <br>
    <br>
    <span onclick="less()" class="linklike">-</span>
    <input type="text">
    <span onclick="more()" class="linklike">+</span>    


  </body>

</html>
```

Quick plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/u7dKekjLg6DpyUjz1a06?p=preview